# Google spreadsheets query range get item to the right

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I am trying to get data from a "flexible" sheet.

The idea is to add in a row a string, and next to it add a formula that from another sheet, it looks up the string and returns the cell just at the right.

### Example:

**Data Sheet: DataCollection**

```
|     |    A    |   B  |    C   |    D   |   
|   1 |  Pepper |   2  |  Sugar |    5   |
|   2 |  Carbon |   3  |  Toy   |   34   |
```

so if in my other sheet, the "Summary" I add to **A1** Sugar I would like to see in **A2** a 5.

### What I have tried so far

**VLOOKUP function**

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,'DataCollection'!A2:B&'DataCollection'!C2:D,1,false)
```

didn't work! I keep receiving a parse formula error.

**QUERY function**

```
=QUERY(DataCollection, "SELECT B WHERE A = A1")
```

that does not work either, I need many different Named Ranges and add a different query for each of them.

Here is a test spreadsheet in case it explains better that my wall of text:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15L5nPGfZ8OXS5Rhl3PdIVhtF7D3QzerkARskflDiJL4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you almost had it. try:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1, {'DataCollection'!A2:B; 'DataCollection'!C2:D}, 2, 0)
```

for an array use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:A, {'DataCollection'!A2:B; 'DataCollection'!C2:D}, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: hi @player0, you cannot set an answer as answered that quick by stackoverflow rules, I tried yesterday and it said I needed to wait, now you get your deserved tick ;), thanks a lot